# android studio getting data from php database and populating the activity

Tags: java, php, json

i'm trying to get the data from the database to fill the activity with them but i'm not getting anything this is the db code i have 2 Textvies 1 image view i'm trying to fill with the data i'm new to mobile programming so need help:

```
public void gettypedet(final int tid, final TextView ttitle, final ImageView timg, final TextView desc) {
    String url = "http://192.168.0.114/mobileshop/product_typrbyid.php?id="+tid;
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    // Request a json response from the provided URL.
    JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject prt) {
                    try {

                        String type=prt.getString("type");
                        int imgname=Integer.parseInt(prt.getString("imagename"));
                        String des=prt.getString("description");
                        ttitle.setText(type);
                        timg.setImageResource(imgname);
                        desc.setText(des);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("error", error.toString());
        }
    });
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(jsonRequest);
}
```

this is my php code i tested it and it's working so shouldn't be the problem:

```
<?php
require_once("connection.php");
$id=$_GET["id"];

$q="Select * from product_type where id='$id'";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$q);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
$types[]=$row;
}
echo (json_encode($types));
    mysqli_free_result($res);

?>
```

this is the activity code here not sure if i did something wrong:

```
public class ptype_detail extends Activity {
int kposition,tposition,id;
TextView ttitle,tdes;
ImageView timg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ptype_detail);
tposition=(Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get("tpos");
kposition=(Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get("kpos");


if (kposition==0)
    id=tposition+5;
else if(kposition==1)
    id=tposition+18;
else if (kposition==2)
    id=tposition+20;
    else
        id=tposition;
ttitle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title) ;
tdes=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.typedes);
timg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.titleimage);
        shop db=new shop(this);
db.gettypedet(id,ttitle,timg,tdes);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? Is anything actually returned from the server? Did you check it with postman or anything similar?

Comment: the php is returning the data i wrote the link to the php in the browser and it's showing the data i need the problem is that the dataisn't showing in android activity

Comment: Did you try logging the response from server in Android Studio?